# Titanium iOS App crashes after taking 25+ images with the camera

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am working on titanium app that is using camera for taking pictures. After taking around 15+ pictures the app will crash. I found the same problem reported on Appcelerator Titanium side https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24389, https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-6225 but I cannot see a solution there. I tried what is suggested there but that is not fixing the problem.

Here is also some simple app. 
Steps:
    1.Click "Add photo" button
    2.Take picture
    3.Click "Use Photo"
    4.Repeat steps 15+ times.

App crashes during the process of taking picture.

Tested with different devices and different Titanium SDKs, it can be reproduced every time.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({});
var view = Ti.UI.createView({});

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    color : '#000000',
    title : "Add photo",
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto'
});
view.add(button);

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    showCamera();
});

function showCamera() {
    Titanium.Media.showCamera({
        showControls : true, 
        mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
        autorotate : true,
        success : function(event) {
        },
        error : function(error) {
        },
        cancel : function() {
        }
    });
}

win.add(view);
win.open();
```

Does anyone know some workaround how can I avoid this crashing?
Thanks.

Comment: Which Ti SDK are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce it on every Ti SDK starting from 6.3.0 to 8.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this SAME issue for a long time.

For iOS, you’ll need to set the `<use-jscore-framework>` flag to true in the tiapp.xml file.
This flag is enabled by default in Titanium SDK 7.0.0 and later.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24206

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I've set that flag to true and with Titanium SDK 8.0.0 it is working. But if I use camera overlay it is still crashing, and in my app I am using overlay.